# MacBook Pro 2008 Aluminum - keyboard problems

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, hardware

I have a late 2008 Macbook Pro all aluminum.

The green caps lock light comes on intermittently: sometimes solid, sometimes flashing. When it comes on, the arrow pointer gets stuck and the screen freezes, or if I'm typing it will stick on a letter and keep repeating it.

Any ideas? …or is it a keyboard replacement?

Answer (score 1):

Try an external usb or wireless keyboard.  If it works ok, then most likely you internal keyboard is damaged and needs repair or replacement.

Answer (score 0):

You could try blasting the dirt from under it (accumulated over Years) with a dust can available in computer stores.

If you feel like a DIY then look [here](http://www.ifixit.com/Guide) for instructions how to replace keyboard.